# SQL - Group By using alias/math calculation/where

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having issues with making a SQL query with a alias in the column and using the alias with group by. My understanding is that group by gets processed before select column alias gets created. I tried using subgroup but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  I'm receiving a "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended "for both queries.  I'm using python format function to insert values such as epoch date int. Can I get help on syntax?

original Attempt

```
  SELECT
                    SUM(wall_clock_time) AS workToBeDone,
                    FLOOR((event_time-{fromTs})/{interval}) as period
                FROM {table}
                WHERE submit_time >= {fromTs} AND event_time < {untilTs}
                GROUP BY period
                ORDER BY period
```

Sub Group attempt

```
           SELECT
                SUM(wall_clock_time) AS workToBeDone,
                period
            FROM
              (
              SELECT
                wall_clock_time,
                (SELECT FLOOR((event_time-{fromTs})/{interval}) FROM {table} WHERE submit_time >= {fromTs} AND event_time < {untilTs}) as period
              FROM
                {table}
              WHERE submit_time >= {fromTs} AND event_time < {untilTs}) AS period
              ) AS inline
            GROUP BY period
            ORDER BY period;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how dates are being passed in this query so I am using actual values to show the query.

```
SELECT SUM(workToBeDone) AS workToBeDone,
PERIOD 
FROM
(SELECT
   wall_clock_time AS workToBeDone,
   FLOOR((event_time- to_date('10-oct-2019','dd-mon-yyyy'))/10) as period
FROM {table}
WHERE submit_time >= to_date('10-oct-2019','dd-mon-yyyy')
AND event_time < to_date('10-oct-2019','dd-mon-yyyy'))
GROUP BY PERIOD
ORDER BY PERIOD;
```

I hope `wall_clock_time` is not the date data type column.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you. We using floats for epoch. Is it possible to optimized this any further?  The query takes a long time to process.